# Deploy Angular + Spring Boot to Tomcat

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, tomcat

May be i do something wrong, but…

1. I’ve made a simple project in Angular on local machine
2. I have create a file proxy.conf.json with code:

   “/inj”: {
   “target”: “http://localhost:8080”,
   “secure”: false
   }
3. i have change my proxy.json to:

   “scripts”: {
   “ng”: “ng”,
   “start”: “ng serve –proxy-config proxy.conf.json”,
   “build”: “ng build”,
4. i have run ng build –base-href /inj/ –prod
5. I add maven framework and SpringBoot to my project
6. i inserted Maven plugin to copy files from Dist to Webapps but i didnt insert plugins for build and run.
7. mvn clean insert
8. I deploy it on remote tomcat and i have 404 error.
9. Ok, I ran npm install on remote machine and i had error that there are no package.json.
10. Ok, i added packege.json to dist, when mvn clean insert
11. I deploy it and run again npm install. Its ok….
12. But – it still 404 error. index html cant find js files

What i do wrong ????

PS: My directory structure:

```
injapp
|
-[angular]
|     |
|     ----[dist]
|     ----[e2e]
|     ----[node_modules]
|     ----[src]
|     ----package.json
|     ----etc
-[src]
|    |
|    -[main]
|       -[java]
|       -[webaps]
|          ---- web.xml
```

PS2: my war file -  is inj.war 
PS3: my web.xml is

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Part of my pom.xml:

My pom.xml for more information:

```
<build>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/angular/dist</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your `pom.xml` file, inside `<configuration>` property provide your working directory for front-end depending path from `pom.xml`. For example:

```
<workingDirectory>../angular/</workingDirectory>
```

Because `npm` should see `package.json` file.

My `<plugin>` config for `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>

    <configuration>
      <nodeVersion>v8.9.4</nodeVersion>
      <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
      <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>install node and npm</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>

      <execution>
        <id>npm install</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>npm</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>

      <execution>
        <id>npm run build</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>npm</goal>
        </goals>

        <configuration>
          <arguments>run build</arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And modified `.angular-cli.json` file to provide output directory:

```
"outDir": "../resources/static",
```

Also in `package.json` modified `build` script to provide `href` option as:

```
"build": "ng build --prod --base-href /app/",
```

So, that's how my build works for tomcat deployment as `app.war`.